# On hover change multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have multiple elements change color on hover. Im trying to get it to work through Javascript, I am not a hero with this.

Basically, what I want to achieve is when I hover either the black div or the white div it should change colours (black becomes white and vice versa).

Javascript:

```
$('#onethirdcolumn').hover(function(){
    $('#onethirdcolumn + .leesmeer').css({
        'color':'#fff',
        'background-color':'#000000'
    });
},function(){
    $('#onethirdcolumn + .leesmeer').css({
        'color':'#000000',
        'background-color':'#fff'
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M828S/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/mewG6/)**</kbd>

```
<div class="box w">TEXT</div>
<div class="box b">TEXT</div>
<div class="box w">TEXT</div>
<div class="box b">TEXT</div>
<div class="box w">TEXT</div>
<div class="box b">TEXT</div>


.box {
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.box.w {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
.box.b {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}


$(function() {
  $(document).on('mouseenter','.box', function() {
    if($('.box').hasClass('w')) {
       $('.box').toggleClass('b');
    }
    if($('.box').hasClass('b')) {
       $('.box').toggleClass('w');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use javascript at all to accomplish this effect.

Assuming html like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container black"></div>
    <div class="container white"></div>
    <div class="container black"></div>
    <div class="container white"></div>
</div>
```

You can achieve the hover effect with the following in CSS:

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Why?  Because they're purdy... */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.black {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff; /* Yay!  Contrast! */
}
.white {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000; /* it DOES matter if you're black or white (if you're text, that is) */
}
.black:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000; /* if you've got text of the opposite color inside */
}
.white:hover {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff; /* and again... */
}
```

And if you want them *all* to change:

```
.wrapper:hover .black { /* Bam!  Spice weasel */
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
.wrapper:hover .white {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M828S/9/)

Comment: Thats not exactly what I am looking for. For example, I have a div (black) with text inside (color: white), when hovering the div should change to white and the text to black. Thanks for the effort tho.

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to try it and will get back to you if it works :)